# How to prove set equivalence with an empty set?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

If I want to prove $A = \emptyset$ for some set A, how would I go?

My first thoughts were to prove it like any set equivalence, by assuming that $x \in \emptyset$ which means that $x \in \emptyset$ or $x \in A$ implying $x \in \emptyset \cup A = A$. But I would not know how to go from $y \in A$ to $y \in \emptyset$ which is impossible obviously.

I also thought about trying $x \in A$ and try to prove $x \notin A$. Will this imply that $A = \emptyset$?

Comment: Your last sentence is fine... We want to prove that $A= \emptyset$; assume not, i.e. if $A$ is not empty, we have $x \in A$ for some $x$. Then we prove $x \notin A$ and we have a contradiction: so, we can negate the assumption that $A$ is not empty and conclude with $A= \emptyset$.

Answer (score 2):

From the definition of equality of sets you need to show that,

$$A\subseteq \emptyset \land \emptyset\subseteq A$$

If any of them is false then the statement cannot be true. Prove that the first assertion is false.

> To prove this just assume that $\exists x\in A$. Then this would imply that $x\in \emptyset$ but that is false.

Answer (score 0):

Let $x$ be arbitrary, assume $x\in A$, and derive a contradiction.

Example: Let $A$ be some set and consider $B=A\cap A^c$. Suppose $x\in B$. By definition, $x\in A$ and $x\notin A$, which is impossible. Hence we have a contradiction and $B=\emptyset$.